# Explain EV in /proc/bus/input/devices data

Tags: linux, devices, proc, events

Can anybody explain to me what the `EV` value in `/proc/bus/input/devices` is?

The keyboard always has value `120013`. Why?

Comment: Please note: Keyboards don't ALWAYS have `0x120013`, but at the minimum they will. You don't want to do `if(ev == 0x120013){ isKeyboard = true; }`, you would want to do `if((ev & 0x120013) == 0x120013){ isKeyboard = true; }`

Answer (score 37):

It represent the `bitmask` for events supported by the device.

Sample of `devices` entry for a AT Keyboard:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=20000 200 20 0 0 0 0 500f 2100002 3803078 f900d401 feffffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7
```

The `B` in front stands for `bitmap`, `N`, `P`, `S`, `U`, `H` are simply first letter in corresponding name value and `I` is for `ID`. [In ordered fashion:](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/02de58b24d2e1b2cf947d57205bd2221d897193c/include/linux/input.h#L45)

- `I => @id: id of the device` [`(struct input_id)`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/02de58b24d2e1b2cf947d57205bd2221d897193c/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L59)

  - `Bus     => id.bustype`
  - `Vendor  => id.vendor`
  - `Product => id.product`
  - `Version => id.version`
- `N => name of the device.`
- `P => physical path to the device in the system hierarchy.`
- `S => sysfs path.`
- `U => unique identification code for the device (if device has it).`
- `H => list of input handles associated with the device.`
- `B => bitmaps`

  - `PROP => device properties and quirks.`
  - **`EV   => types of events supported by the device.`**
  - `KEY  => keys/buttons this device has.`
  - `MSC  => miscellaneous events supported by the device.`
  - `LED  => leds present on the device.`

---

### Bitmasks

As you know computers deal in binary, so:

```
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
3 = 0011
4 = 0100
5 = 0101
...
```

So if i have a bitmap with value `5` that one would hold bits 0 and 2 in other
word one can give each number a name and check if they correspond to a value.

E.g.

```
A = 1,  001
B = 2,  010
C = 4,  100
```

Then if I have `MYVAR = 5` which is `101` in binary this would check out:

```
MYVAR & A == TRUE   (101 & 001 => 001)
MYVAR & B == FALSE  (101 & 010 => 000)
MYVAR & C == TRUE   (101 & 100 => 100 )
```

Thus my var *has* A and C.

---

The kernel uses a bit more sophisticated/complex way, and set bits by
offset. One reason being that more bits then is available in one computer (CPU) integer is used. For example look at the `KEY` bitmap.

So, if we say:

```
A = 0
B = 1
C = 6
...
```

And then

```
target = 0;
set_bit(A, target);  => target ==      0001
set_bit(C, target);  => target == 0100 0001
```

---

### Decoding `120013`

The value `120013` is a hexadecimal. As binary it gives us:

```
0x120013 == 0001 0010 0000 0000 0001 0011 binary
               1    2    0    0    1    3
```

Numbered from right they are:

```
   2            1               <= offset (10's)
3210 9876 5432 1098 7654 3210   <= offset (counted from right)
0001 0010 0000 0000 0001 0011   <= binary

Set bits are:
   0, 1, 4, 17, 20
```

Then check [`input-event-codes.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h) you find that they correspond to:

```
   0  EV_SYN (0x00)
   1  EV_KEY (0x01)
   4  EV_MSC (0x04)
  17  EV_LED (0x11)
  20  EV_REP (0x14)
```

To check what they mean a quick introduction is given by [Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/event-codes.html).

```
* EV_SYN:
  - Used as markers to separate events. Events may be separated in time or in
    space, such as with the multitouch protocol.

* EV_KEY:
  - Used to describe state changes of keyboards, buttons, or other key-like
    devices.

* EV_MSC:
  - Used to describe miscellaneous input data that do not fit into other types.

* EV_LED:
  - Used to turn LEDs on devices on and off.

* EV_REP:
  - Used for autorepeating devices.
```

---

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94329/28489), ***"EDIT 2 (continued):"*** in particular, might be of interest.

Comment: This answer is amazing!